# Passing multiple variable in strinG

Tags: php, string

```
<tr class="data_row">
    <td align="left"><?php echo  $daerah_ejen  ?>&nbsp;</td>

    <?php
            //link maklumat terperinci daerah
    $detail_name_link = '<a onmouseover="Tip(\'Klik untuk lihat maklumat terperinci\')" onmouseout="UnTip()" href=laporan_kk_detail.php?daerah_ejen='.$daerah_ejen.'&kumpulan_ejen ='.$kumpulan_ejen.'>'.number_format($jumlah, 0, '.', ',').'</a>';
    ?>
    <!--<td align="right"><?php echo  number_format($jumlah, 0, '.', ',')  ?>&nbsp;</td>-->
    <td align="right"><?php echo  $detail_name_link  ?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

This is my code, when I pass variable `$daerah_ejen` in href, it just passes the first word only. Example, it should be passing `"HULU SELANGOR"`, but then it only passes `"HULU"` on the other page.

Can you help me fix the code, or make any suggestion to declare that variable to a string?

Comment: Probably need to encode `$daerah_ejen` because of spaces. Or need to have `href="…` and not `href=…`

Comment: encode?? how to pass that variable?

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode parameter in the url as :

```
    $daerah_ejen = urlencode($daerah_ejen); // the url parameter is encoded 
    $kumpulan_ejen = urlencode($kumpulan_ejen);// the url parameter is encoded 
    $detail_name_link = '<a onmouseover="Tip(\'Klik untuk lihat maklumat terperinci\')" onmouseout="UnTip()" href="laporan_kk_detail.php?daerah_ejen='.$daerah_ejen.'&kumpulan_ejen ='.$kumpulan_ejen.'">'.number_format($jumlah, 0, '.', ',').'</a>';
```

This will do the job.

for more about the urlencode [**refer this**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Hope this will help!

Comment: thanks, it solved. but i have another problem appear. why the variable $kumpulan_ejen not pass. I got the below url
/laporan_kk_detail.php?daerah_ejen=SABAK+BERNAM&kumpulan_ejen

Comment: @user3487681 what is the type of $kumpulan_ejen variable? what does it content? if the value having space or special characters then only do the urlencoding, try updated answer

Comment: @user3487681 maybe its because of `'&kumpulan_ejen ='` try removing that space.